# How to select all the field in content type

Tags: entities

How to select all the fields created in custom content type using select query.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=') // select nodes
 ->propertyCondition('type', 'testimonials', '=') //type testimonials   
 ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'desc') //most recent first 
 ->range(0,2) // limit
 ->execute(); 
$testimonials = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
```

Comment: what u want to do?

Comment: $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=') // select nodes
            ->propertyCondition('type', 'testimonials', '=') //type testimonials
            ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'desc') //most recent first
            ->range(0,2) // limit
            ->execute();
        
$testimonials = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));

Comment: Sorry but for the time being this needs to be closed. The code you've put in the question doesn't match up with the code you say you're using in the comments, and it's impossible to understand what you're doing, and what your issue actually is. You mention error messages, yet you haven't included them in your question. Please describe your _actual_ problem in the question, **in detail**, and keep it scoped to a single topic. Then the question can be re-opened

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind my saying, you *don't* want to do that manually. Drupal has a rich API which you should use.

The standard method to load a node and all of its fields/extra data, is [`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7):

```
$node = node_load($nid);
```

If you're trying to avoid the overhead of the 'extra' (non-field) data, then you can use [`field_attach_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7) along with a basic DB query to get a reasonable node object with all fields attached.

```
// Get base node data (aka 'properties')
$node = db_query('SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid = :nid', array(':nid' => $nid))->fetchObject();

// Attach the fields
field_attach_load('node', array($node));
```

It is possible, of course, to query the database manually for all of this data, but when the functionality has already been written for you there doesn't seem any point.

Comment: I want to get the fields of one particular content type. I want to use those fields based on the HTML design

Comment: Do you mean the field structure rather than field data?

Comment: I want to display particular field value added in the content type custom fields

Comment: <?php 
$type = "testimonials";
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->propertyCondition('type', array('testimonials', 'page', 'blog'))
  ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
  ->range(0, 2);
$result = $query->execute();    
$myPosts = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));   
    foreach($myPosts as $products):
    ?>

Comment: I 'm trying like this. But it displays error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Cannot unset string offsets in entity.inc on line 167

Comment: And you've confirmed that `$result['node']` isn't empty?

Comment: propertyCondition('type', array('testimonials', 'page', 'blog')) is where I gone wrong. I have only page and testimonials content type

Comment: Undefined index: und in include() page--testimonials.tpl.php). Please help me out. This error message I seen in Admin page

Comment: Sorry but you seem to be using this site as your debugging service, which is not what it's for. If you have a _real_, _substantial_, _useful_ question, please edit the original body and ask it. Otherwise this will simply have to be closed as not a real question